# Handling events for CompactCalendarView calendar in android

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

i am using [CompactCalendarView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3436) for adding, deleting, viewing and updating events,

1. Every time when i load my fragment ( `CompactCalendarView` activity where my calendar is shown) I am making call to my REST API fetching events and adding back to the `CompactCalendarView` and i don't know what i am doing is right as this may make my events notifications to be removed(For every event added i am setting a notification alert so that user is notified about the event)
2. Also as every time i the activity is loaded i dont find a check for if the event is already present
3. I also what to sync `CompactCalendarView` to sync with google account calendar

Any help in enlightening me what to do as its pretty confusing for me to understand whats happening in [CompactCalendarView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3436)

Thnaks.